# Angular routing module can use not exported component from another module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, angular-module

why Angular routing module can directly use not exported component from another module

A routing ngModule

```
...
{
    path: 'home',
    component: bComponent    // it is not exported in B module
}
```

B ngModule

```
{
    declarations: [bComponent],
    // not exporting bComponent, but it still can be used in A routing ngModule. Why?
}
```

Comment: try to add exported component like this: exports: [Component that you want to export here]

Comment: I know how to use export components and use them in other modules , but I do not understand why angular routing module can use component directly from other modules even if that component is not exported.